# RM ANOVA with R - wrong output

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am performing a RM two-way ANOVA with R, with the aov() function, which gave me quite good results for a dataset (the same results I had with another Statistic software), but I cannot understand why with a similar dataset I get the wrong output.

Here my dataset & code

```
t <- structure(list(Light = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), 
Culture = c("mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "mono", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co", "co"),
Time = c(-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), 
PAM = c(0.732,0.7425,0.763,0.715,0.701,0.741,0.7265,0.752,0.717,0.724,0.758,0.724,0.747, 0.755,0.789, 0.655,0.779,0.695,0.719,0.758,0.695,0.7105,0.681,0.742,0.759,0.7275,0.75,0.679,0.706,0.704,0.715,0.67,0.74,0.697,0.763,0.749,0.756,0.692,0.684,0.711,0.734,0.7315,0.7065,0.7115,0.696,0.649,0.6675,0.686,0.6745,0.649,0.757,0.688,0.725,0.688,0.736,0.704,0.688,0.722,0.659,0.627,0.7265,0.712,0.734,0.743,0.718,0.702,0.674,0.709,0.7,0.687,0.744,0.705,0.751,0.733,0.753,0.729,0.716,0.713,0.643,0.71,0.7235,0.677,0.711,0.718,0.7045,0.6625,0.6195,0.625, 0.634, 0.614,0.715, 0.66,0.707,0.704,0.652,0.631,0.639,0.629,0.655,0.637,0.737,0.733, 0.7365,0.7145,0.7105,0.674, 0.679,0.6975,0.685,0.6815,0.746,0.667,0.753,0.711,0.737,0.705,0.693, 0.697,0.65, 0.618,0.7655,0.725,0.7395,0.7065,0.7255,0.5815, 0.645, 0.6385,0.601,0.4795, 0.69,0.703, 0.727, 0.702,0.662,0.679,0.678,0.636, 0.649,0.527),  
Subject = c("DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20", "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4", "DM5", "DM6", "DM7", "DM8", "DM9", "DM10", "DM11", "DM12", "DM13", "DM14", "DM15", "DM16", "DM17", "DM18", "DM19", "DM20")),
.Names = c("Light", "Culture", "Time", "PAM", "Subject"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:140)

attach(t)           
summary(t)

Light <- as.factor(Light)
Time <- as.factor(Time)
Culture <- as.factor(Culture)

fit <- aov(PAM ~ Time*Light*Culture + Error(Subject/(Light*Culture*Time)),
       data = t, projections = FALSE, qr = TRUE, contrasts = NULL)
summary(fit)
```

and here what I get as result

```
Error: Subject
              Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Light          1 0.06780 0.06780  37.412 1.49e-05 ***
Culture        1 0.00024 0.00024   0.131    0.723    
Light:Culture  1 0.00113 0.00113   0.621    0.442    
Residuals     16 0.02900 0.00181                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Subject:Time
                   Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Time                6 0.08500 0.014166  17.596 1.20e-13 ***
Time:Light          6 0.03279 0.005465   6.788 5.08e-06 ***
Time:Culture        6 0.00135 0.000225   0.280   0.9453    
Time:Light:Culture  6 0.00961 0.001602   1.990   0.0746 .  
Residuals          96 0.07729 0.000805                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Another thing is that I would need to test for sphericity as well. Can someone help me to understand how to do that with aov()? The only way I found was in a post, but using Anova() function.

Many thanks

Comment: What if you add `Subject <- as.factor(Subject)` ?

Comment: It didn't change anything, but thanks. Anyway I found the way with aov_ez() function.